# Error in final launch sequence: Failed to execute MI command:

Tags: stm32, bluepill

I am using STM32F103C8T6 and ST-Link V2 Programmer. I am in Windows 11.

Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
target remote localhost:61234

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:61234: Connection timed out.
Failed to execute MI command:
target remote localhost:61234

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:61234: Connection timed out.
localhost:61234: Connection timed out.

The above is the error message. Tried all methods but nothing works.

Comment: Please provide more context: What are you trying to do when these error message occur (upload software, run software etc.)? What software are you using to execute this action? Please add the additional information to the question.

Comment: In the past, you have never accepted an answer to your questions. Did you never receive an answer that worked, or are you not familiar with best practices on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Codo many people here do not bother to say "thank you". We "have" to help them, but they do not have to show appreciation.